# What is MIME? What is it for exactly?

Tags: html

I was reading an article on COMET recently I have came across many times the word MIME? I googled it found that MIME is Multipurpose Internet Mail Extension. And also i came across the sentence

> multipart/x-mixed-replace" feature of
>   the MIME standard . .

What does **multipart/x-mixed-replace** means in terms of MIME? And even what is MIME used for? And why?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Mixed-Replace_.28Experimental.29

Comment: @ukhardy: however the above link is correct, it doesnt explain what i was seen for ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MIME type is a description of the data returned by a request on the Internet (originally used by e-mail, and later used by many parts of the web).

Since data can take hundreds (if not thousands) of forms, both textual and binary, it helps a program to know what type of data it is dealing with, rather than trying to write code that figures it out automatically.

The program can use this data to either select a handler (jpg vs. png), or simply refuse to handle data that isn't a type it knows how to handle, or doesn't want to deal with (e.g. an mp3, where it is expecting xml).

This can also be used to classify data (search engines), or restrict it (in a web proxy or e-mail server).

Some examples:

- image/gif
- text/html
- video/mpeg
- application/zip
- application/x-font-ttf

For bigger lists of MIME type examples, see these links:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#List_of_common_media_types
- http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/index.html

Comment: So it means that all browser that renders any page have to look into this MIME type right? So is that there is any parser or interpreter in browser to **find** what type it has been used? So that it can render correctly?

Comment: @Anto: I am not sure for the browsers themselves, but there is definitely software in existence that will attempt to corroborate the MIME type.  See http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Mime_type_detection for one example.  I wouldn't be surprised if it were common in browsers, too, because that would be a way to thwart potential security threats early on, rather than only relying on the parsers to be 100% bug free.  For example: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/bulletin/ms01-020.mspx

Answer (score 1):

> An Internet media type, originally called a MIME type after MIME (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions) and sometimes a Content-type after the name of a header in several protocols whose value is such a type, is a two-part identifier for file formats on the Internet.

[More here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type).

Comment: Well in my original answer, I forgot to mention that the acronym is correct, but it really has little to do with "mail" anymore.  The article should help you out.

Answer (score 1):

It's a way of describing a document (or file).

Programs like mail readers and web browsers use the "mime-type" of a document to determine how to handle it.

Each mime type is a string that describes contents

```
    multipart/x-mixed-replace
```

Is a particular mime type which typically is used for http server push streams.